Symmetry in the triple integral
I don't really understand how to explain one transition in a task:

To investigate the convergence of the integral $\iiint\limits_\Omega\frac{dxdydz}{|x+y-z|^p}, \; \Omega = \{ (x,y,x) | \; |x| \leqslant 1, |y| \leqslant 1, |z| \leqslant 1\}$

I have an idea to make the next transition $\iiint\limits_\Omega\frac{dxdydz}{|x+y-z|^p} = 2\iiint\limits_{\substack{|x| \leqslant 1 \\ |y| \leqslant 1 \\ |z| \leqslant 1 \\ x+y-x \geqslant 0}} \frac{dxdydz}{(x+y-x)^p}$
And then, in general, it is clear how to decide, but why can I do this? Because I have a symmetrical area - that is, a cube and there the module is also symmetrical, but in general it still somehow confuses me a little

You can split the set $\Omega$ into the union of $\Omega_+$ and $\Omega_-$ according to the sign of $x+y-z.$ The case $x+y-z=0$ can be ignored. Then applying the substitution $(x,y,z)\mapsto (-x,-y,-z)$ maps $\Omega_-$ onto $\Omega_+.$

@Ryszard Szwarc And that's it, now it's clear, only one thing is not clear, why instead of answering, you wrote it down in the comment, so it would be a closed question. Thanks!
